# Creating new Fragment vs Refreshing existing one - what is better for performance?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to implement default design patterns for tablets and handsets:
[image]

But I don't clearly understand should I recreate Fragment B every `listView.setOnItemClickListener` call or I need just to update the views of fragment B? What is better for performance and why?

I think creating new Fragment (Activity) instead of refreshing the existing one gives more advantages:

1. More simple code.
2. Ability to use normal activity stack to handle back-navigation.

**But why [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments) uses updating fragment's content in their explanation?**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TitlesFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    /** This is a callback that the list fragment (Fragment A)
        calls when a list item is selected */
    public void onItemSelected(int position) {
        DisplayFragment displayFrag = (DisplayFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.display_frag);
        if (displayFrag == null) {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is not in the layout (handset layout),
            // so start DisplayActivity (Activity B)
            // and pass it the info about the selected item
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is in the layout (tablet layout),
            // so tell the fragment to update
            displayFrag.updateContent(position); //WHY?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation the second approach is used: on a tablet - multiple fragments in one activity; on a handset - separate activities to host each fragment. By searching `displayFrag` you actually check if it's a two-pane mode.
If there is no fragment then you have to start a new activity, otherwise update content.

Creating a new fragment can simplify code but also stress a garbage collector. It also varies depending on specific update, you are not only creating new objects but may rebuild full view hierarchy.

Smart reusing always gives a better performance (think about viewholder pattern) sometimes in sacrifice of readability.